# How to properly enable DNSoverTLS on Systemd

Tags: dns, networkmanager, systemd-resolved

I came across this strange problem the other day. I enabled DNS over TLS(DoT) months ago on my laptop. My laptop had been sitting at home until I decided to take it with me to town.

Recently I discovered that systemd-resolved wasn't using DoT when connected to the Wi-Fi.

```
Link 8 (wlp2s0)
      Current Scopes: DNS LLMNR/IPv4 LLMNR/IPv6
DefaultRoute setting: yes                      
       LLMNR setting: yes                      
MulticastDNS setting: no                       
  DNSOverTLS setting: opportunistic                      
      DNSSEC setting: no                       
    DNSSEC supported: no                       
  Current DNS Server: 192.168.42.129           
         DNS Servers: 192.168.42.129           
          DNS Domain: ~.
```

systemd-resolved was sending UDP packets to the ISP DNS server(192.168.42.129) the entire time! The journal shows:

```
systemd-resolved[]: Using degraded feature set (UDP+EDNS0) for DNS server ...
```

The problem was that NetworkManager was still configured to push DNS servers from DHCP to systemd-resolved. This resulted in the systemd-resolved overriding the global setting for the interface. I had to disable it by adding `systemd-resolved=false` in *NetworkManager.conf*.

Before I go to the github page to file a bug, I just wanted to see if anyone knew about this. All the materials online says all you need to do is adding `dns=systemd-resolved` and `DNSOverTLS=(whichever)`.

Answer (score 0):

If you set `Domains=~.` in your `/etc/systemd/resolved.conf`, systemd-resolved will use the global configuration in preference to any per-link configuration.  Otherwise, as you've observed, the per-link configuration takes precedence.